# MODULE_NOT_FOUND error for already installed npm package

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I am seeing an error when I run a command with npm-run-all:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'define-properties'
Require stack:
- /local/node/src/Widgets/node_modules/string.prototype.padend/index.js
- /local/node/src/Widgets/node_modules/npm-run-all/lib/run-task.js
- /local/node/src/Widgets/node_modules/npm-run-all/lib/run-tasks.js
- /local/node/src/Widgets/node_modules/npm-run-all/lib/index.js
- /local/node/src/Widgets/node_modules/npm-run-all/bin/run-s/main.js
- /local/node/src/Widgets/node_modules/npm-run-all/bin/common/bootstrap.js
- /local/node/src/Widgets/node_modules/npm-run-all/bin/run-s/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:871:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1098:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:18)
```

Even though I already have the module installed by running `npm install define-properties --save`

```
"@babel/core": "^7.22.5",
"@babel/plugin-syntax-typescript": "^7.22.5",
"@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.5",
"@testing-library/dom": "^9.3.1",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
"@testing-library/react": "^12.1.5",
"@types/enzyme": "^3.10.13",
"@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
"@types/node": "^20.3.1",
"@types/react": "^18.2.12",
"@types/react-dom": "^18.2.5",
"@types/testing-library__jest-dom": "^5.14.6",
"@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.8.0",
"babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
"balanced-match": "^2.0.0",
"classnames": "^2.3.2",
"css-loader": "^6.8.1",
"define-properties": "^1.2.0",
"npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
"prettier": "^2.8.8",
"read-pkg": "^8.0.0",
"ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
"ts-loader": "^9.4.3",
"ts-node": "^10.9.1",
"ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
"tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
"typescript": "^4.9.5",
"whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.2"
```

Scripts look like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "check-prettier": "npx prettier --check .",
    "check-ts": "run-s tsc-clean tsc-build tsc-clean",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist && rm -rf node_modules",
    "concurrent-tasks-release": "run-p clean check-prettier check-ts",
    "build": "tsc",
    "build-farm:clean:npm": "rm -fr node_modules",
    "build-farm:clean:workspace": "npm run clean-workspace",
    "build-farm:clean:dev-server": "rm -fr ./dev-server",
    "build-farm:clean:tests": "find ./src -name __tests__ -type d -print0  | xargs -0 rm -rf",
    "release": "run-s concurrent-tasks-release test",
    "tsc-clean": "mkdir -p ./build/private/tmp/check-ts-build && rm -rf ./build/private/tmp/check-ts-build",
    "tsc-build": "tsc --build ./tsconfig.json",
    "test": "npm run test:unit",
    "test:unit": "jest -c ./jest/unit/jest.config.js --runInBand",
  },
```

Any idea how to resolve this? I've also deleted `node_modules` folder in case it's a cache issue.

Comment: How are you running your npm script and what does your `scripts` look like from pkg json? What about `npm ls define-properties`?

Comment: define-properties graph is empty.

Comment: Added scripts to the question

Answer (score 0):

npm-run-all does not like npx see this open [issue](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/issues/209)

Do this:

1. install:

> npm install npm-run-all

2. replace line wirh npx in script to:

```json
    "scripts": 
     {
     "check-prettier": "npm-run-all prettier --check .",
    },
```

Comment: I still see the same error if I remove prettier from the release script entirely. I believe the error is on check-ts

Comment: What error are you getting with check-ts ?

Comment: The one in the question, where define-properties isn't found (even though it is installed)

Comment: im sure it is not on the path where it should be, please run: npm list and paste the output here

Comment: In fact if you install define-properties globally it will not complain, if you want to give it a try run(notice the -g): npm install define-properties -g